# Proper "placeholder" in pageBlockSectionItems and PanelGrids

Tags: visualforce, pageblocksection, panelgrid

Unsure of how to ask that really but on my page I have some pageBlockSectionItems with labels and some pageBlockSectionItems without. The ones without the labels have the data side shifted to the left (where the label would be) because there is no label. So in order to keep everything aligned I have just put a blank outputlabel in the pageBlockSectionItem.

Same with panelGrids, I have a 2 column + 3 row panelGrid like below

```
  Item1 |
-------------------
  Item2 |  Item 3
--------------------
  Item4 |
```

As you can see the slot next to Item1 is empty. But if I leave it actually empty Item2 slides up and fills in that top-right slot. So I just put an empty outputPanel there to fill it and push Item2 down.

These "placeholders" however not only cause the code to become less readable but I am also now recieving a "Maximum Viewstate size exceeded" which this method is likely contributing to. So I ask is there a proper way to fill those spaces?

Answer (score 2):

For reducing viewstate size and to get a more flexible design you can use a native HTML tags together with 'apex:repeat'.

```
<table border="0">
    <apex:repeat val="{!myList}" variable="item">
        <tr>
            <td>{!item.Field1__c}</td>
            <td>{!item.Field1__c}</td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
```